# Create folder on desktop with no messages, if exist, ignore

Tags: vba, directory

I need to create a VBA macro when workbook opens, and create a desktop folder on /FATURAS.

If that folder not exist, open message box with information that folder was created, if already exist, ignore and do not alert message.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please note that SO is not a code writing service. You have to do your own research, attempt it and if you are stuck at a particular point, feel free to post a question with your code attempt and explain what's not working (Error? which line and what message? Not working? explain in details and what are you expecting)

Comment: If you have already attempted it, please edit your question and include your code in the question for us to help you.

Comment: I found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

        Dim cOb As Variant
        Dim FolderName As String, FolderExists As String
        FolderName = "C:\Users\AAAAA\Desktop\A New Folder" '---->Change folder name to suit. Change the AAAAA to your requirement.
        FolderExists = Dir(FolderName, vbDirectory)
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       
       If FolderExists = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "The desktop folder doesn't exist. Creating a new folder now.", vbExclamation, "INFORMATION"
            cOb = CreateObject("wscript.shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\" & "A New Folder" '--->Change folder name to suit.
            MkDir cOb
            Else: Exit Sub
       End If
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you need to disable and enable `ScreenUpdating` property since you did not perform any action on the workbook so you can remove those lines. You can also remove `Else: Exit Sub` since your code would have exit the sub anyway